# Can I alter only the top and bottom paddings with one property?

Tags: css

I have a paragraph on a web page with 20 pixel margins on all 4 sides. I want to alter just the top and bottom paddings with a single property (so `padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;` will not do).

What I have tried is demonstrated here.

http://jsfiddle.net/nFCru/1/

In this Fiddle, I tried to use `padding: 30px inherit;` to alter just the top and bottom paddings of a paragraph. However, this property-value pair sets the left and right paddings to 0 in addition to altering the top and bottom paddings.

```
p {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 20px;    
}

/* 
 * Here's my failed attempt at only altering the top 
 * and bottom padding values. The left and right padding
 * values are changing even if I use inherit.
 */

p {
 padding: 30px inherit;   
}​
```

Can I alter only the top and bottom paddings with one property?

Comment: Maybe explaining why 2 properties isn't an option would help give you a better solution.

Comment: I think it's a good question. Sure you can write them out; in this case it doesn't matter that much. But what if you want to change three borders - color, style and width, while leaving the fourth intact. You'd have no choice but to write that out in full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. `inherit` means the element inherits the padding from its parent. That is, the body (or whatever element the p sits in), not the "original" p in the stylesheet. To leave the left and right padding intact, all you can do is use the two properties as you described.

Answer (score 4):

In short, no.

The only allowable attributes for padding are width (fixed) or percentage, or inherit (from the parent element). There is no way to inherit values already set.

To set the individual padding values you must use the individual properties.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

Answer (score 4):

Until now you couldn't. But even though this is a very old question I thought I'd update it with a new answer.

With the [CSS Logical Properties and Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-logical-1/#padding-properties) specification, which is supported by all major browsers since 2021, you are now able to do this. It allows you to specify the start and end of a block or inline padding which is dependent on writing mode and direction instead of simple left-to-right based on the screen in front of you.

If you wanted to specify a 10px padding on the top and bottom of an element you could achieve this with the following for example:

```
.element {
    padding-block: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanted to change the top and bottom, just use the shorthand padding:30px 0px 30px; would be top, right, bottom.

Comment: padding:30px 0px 30px; would set top 30px left & right 0px bottom 30px and would be effectively the same as setting padding: 30px 0;

Answer (score 1):

Inherit basically inherits only the parent element's style but in your case you can't use inherit but you can do the following for two "p" elements using class.

```
p{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;    
}

p.another{
    padding: 30px 20px;  
}
<p>A Paragraph with 20px top, right, bottom, left</p>
<p class="another">Another Paragraph with 30px top, 20px right, 30px bottom, 20px left</p>
```